# Python urlparse urljoin with query variable

Tags: python

I want to join the `url1` and `url2`:

```
url1 = "https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA"
url2 = "&start=10"
```

to:

```
combine =   https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start=10
```

so that I can change `url2` to get start=10,start=20....

It's a function like:

```
link ="https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA"
start = 10
def combineurl(link,num):
    url1 = link
    url2 = '&start={start}'.format(start=num)
    global start
    start +=10
    return url1 + url2
print combineurl(link,start)
```

And next time, I will throw `combineurl(link,start)` to  `def combineurl`

```
print combineurl(combineurl(link,start),start)
```

the result will be : `https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start=20&start=30`
But what I need is `https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start=30`

How can I get this result I want ??
Thank you

Comment: combine = url1 + url2?

Comment: sorry I didn't describe well,I edit it

Answer (score 0):

You may try format method of string object:

```
>>> url1 = "https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start={0}"
>>> url2 = url1.format(10)
>>> url2
'https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start=10'
>>> url3 = url1.format(20)
>>> url3
'https://www.test.com.tw/search?q=AAA&start=20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just looking for string concatenation:

```
theurl = url1 + url2
```

That's not the job of `urllib.urljoin', which is more about combining absolute and relative URLs properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you described in your edit

```
def combineurl(link,num):
    link = link.split("&start")[0]
    return link + '&start={0}'.format(num)
```